# ASP response.write not doing anything

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm writing a very simple ASP program inside HTML to write "hello". However when I open it in internet Explorer on Windows 7 it doesn't show anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("hello")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you viewing it via a webserver?

Comment: I have it saved in my documents on the college server and then I drag it into IE. Is that right?

Comment: No.  Classic ASP is server side code.  you need to view it via a URL eg http:// yourcollegeserverip/yourpage.asp, you can't just open it directly in a browser.

Comment: @John: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the use of ASP in your page?

At the very top you should put:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
```

Also, do you have a server delivering the page, and are visiting a `.asp` extension?

Comment: Probably not really necessary to declare vbscript, as that is usually the default scripting language, but it's certainly good practice